# How to communicate flex 4 + aspx directly?

Tags: c#, apache-flex, excel, export, communication

I'd like to know if it's possible to communicate flex 4 with a file .aspx..
My problem is.. I'm trying to export a datagrid to excel and both parts are right, except because they are not communicating.. When I open with Visual Studio the url is = localhost\casaws\ExportExcel and when I open with flex the url is localhost:8080\casa\ExportExcel... that's the problem... if someone knows how to resolv this problem I'd thank...

Comment: Are you building an Air app or a browser based app?

Answer (score 0):

From Flex, you can call remote service using [RemoteObject](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/remoting/mxml/RemoteObject.html?filter_coldfusion=9&filter_flex=3&filter_flashplayer=10&filter_air=1.5), [WebService](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/soap/mxml/WebService.html?filter_flex=4.1&filter_flashplayer=10.1&filter_air=2), or [HTTPService](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/http/mxml/HTTPService.html?filter_flex=4.1&filter_flashplayer=10.1&filter_air=2).

I'm not sure what you mean by "directly", but one of those should work for you, depending on the implementation of your service layer.

How are you currently trying to communicate between the two?  In Flex, were are you specifying the remote URL?  Were you sure to include the port?  IF you're using RemoteObject, the port (and other information) are usually defined in a service-config.xml file.